# Am I targeting the correct specs for a controller Request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a sample controller with the following action, and am writing a Request spec for it:

```
def subscribe_user
  concept = UsersConcept::Subscribe.new(user_params)
  concept.run

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: concept.notice_msg }
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :channel_id)
end
```

Am I correct to write tests for the following:

1. `UsersConcept::Subscribe` calls `new`
2. the result from #1 above calls `run`

Or should I just focus on writing test for verifying redirects, error messages, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Stop writing controller tests, make Request specs

Rails and RSpec teams suggest replacing or removing your app’s controller tests (also known as the functional test layer), in favor of directly testing models (units), or with higher-level integration tests.

Here you can find the article and some example code:

https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html

For your action you could test the redirection, success or error messages, a change in die DB for your subscription table...

Comment: ah yes I actually am writing a Request spec,
i am able to write test that will, for example, verify that the action redirects to the correct page.
but i would like to test simple things like verifying that some classes called methods as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer though, do you think i should not test for the ones i listed on the question?

Comment: Have you walked through the rspec documentation ? You are asking really basic stuff. And to help you better you should post code of your started test. For example to test if a model or Class receive a method call you can do `expect(classOrModel).to receive(:foo)` and foo is the method

Comment: Yes I am still really a beginner writing rspec tests. Maybe my question was wrong, maybe I should ask if I am targeting the correct tests to write.
But yes thank you I am using expect(UserConcept..).to receive(:new) now.